# Prevent touch transfer to superview from UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I have a custom vertical range slider and handling the movements of heads using touchBegan, touchMoved and touchEnded. When I try to slide the head, it slides a bit and after that touch is cancelled and interactive dismiss transition starts on iOS 13. I want to prevent the touch to transfer while sliding, to the superview. How we can achieve that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try using another gesture recognizer to the view with another selector

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnBubble)];
    [self.bubbleView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap2 = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnMainView)];
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap2];


-(void)tappedOnMainView
{
    NSLog(@"touched on main View");
    [self.vwToShow setHidden:NO];
}
-(void)tappedOnView
{
    NSLog(@"tapped on slider");
    [self.vwToShow setHidden:YES];
}
```

UIView inherits from UIResponder, and basic touch events are detected by the view that triggers the touches began events. The subviews that you added in the main view also responds to the touches began method.Thats very basic. You have also added a selector method with tap gesture recognizer.

If you still want to use touchBegan ,  I think you should do something like this:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    if(theTouchLocation is inside your bubble)
    {
        do something with the touch
    }
    else
    {
        //send the touch to the next view in the hierarchy ( your large view )
       [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
       [[self nextResponder] touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    }
}
```